# how to fetch data from table using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch an email from a particular row or based on the `id_code` from `people` table... That is, say I enter a `id_code = 456`,  if the id code exists the email of that specific `id_code` has to be retrieved, and generate a token number and insert the token number into the people table. After the token is generated and inserted, a URL link has to be sent with the token and an id.

How would i do that since i am a beginner, can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Here is what I did so far:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    session_start();

    include 'includes/db.php';
    include 'includes/token.php';

    //global
    $id_code = strtoupper(trim($_POST['id_code']));

    if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id_code = :id_code";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (!empty($_POST['id_code'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM people WHERE id_code = $id_code";

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else {
            //echo "<br/>Validated: FALSE<br/>"; die();
            echo 'You are not Registered..Please Contact support';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what is id_code in your table? the id of the person or the id of the message?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see `$id_code` is not defined. The value you might want to use is stored in `$_POST['id_code']` so you should do something like `$id_code = $_POST['id_code'];` in front of your IF condition, otherwise `$id_code` is undefined.

Update: you already did it with `$ccode`, use this for the binding and it should work.

```
$stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
```

replaced by

```
$stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $ccode);
```

## UPDATE

please try the following code and post the result of the var_dump():

```
<?php
    error_reporting(1);
    session_start();

    include 'includes/db.php';
    include 'includes/token.php';

    //global
    $id_code = strtoupper(trim($_POST['id_code']));

    var_dump("ID: ".$id_code);

    if ($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE id_code = :id_code";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        var_dump("Result: ".$result);

        if (!empty($_POST['id_code'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM people WHERE id_code = $id_code";

            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result2 = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            var_dump("Result2: ".$result2);

        } else {
            //echo "<br/>Validated: FALSE<br/>"; die();
            echo 'You are not Registered..Please Contact support';
        }
    }
?>
```

Do you get any output from your script?

Comment: i made a typo, the code should have been $idcode = strtoupper(trim($_POST['id_code'])); and i made it global..how will i get the email say doe@domian.com from that id_code since i am going to type a id_code and if that id exists i have to get the email else issue a warning.

Comment: `$idcode` is still not equal to `$id_code`. You should enable errormessages in order to debug easier: `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the beginning of your script should enable it.

Comment: typo again, my fault now it has been changed, i just need to fetch the email where id_code is equal to the value that i type, what is wrong with the script?

Comment: please try out my updated code above and post the results

Comment: this is the output i got ---string(4) "ID: "

Comment: Okay, so `$id_code = strtoupper(trim($_POST['id_code']));` does not contain an ID. Try out `$id_code = 1` (or any other existing ID in your database) to see if the rest of the script works correctly. After this check the form that provides the input of `$_POST['id_code']` and see if the input field is named correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct binding for second query too  (you have assigned $id_code)

```
 if (!empty($_POST['id_code'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT email FROM people WHERE id_code = :id_code";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_code', $id_code);
        echo $email;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```